# Parallel processing for loop in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, parallel-processing

Want to parallel process the below code. Due to some reason I've to subset and then apply function. Note that the subset size will not be consistent.

```
for i in range(0, df['col1'].max()+1):
    subset = df[ df['col1'] == i ]
    subset_result = func(subset)
    result = result.append(subset_result)
```

Comment: The below can be used for equal split of dataframe. How can I use it for unequal subsets.cores=mp.cpu_count()

df_split = np.array_split(df, cores, axis=0)

# create the multiprocessing pool
pool = Pool(cores)

# process the DataFrame by mapping function to each df across the pool
df_out = np.vstack(pool.map(func, df_split))

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import multiprocessing

def f(x):
    return x*x

def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_core = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes= n_core)

    data = range(0, 8)
    subsets = chunks(data, n_core)
    subset_results = []
    for subset in subsets:
        subset_results.append(p.map(f, subset))

    print(subset_results)
```

In your case, a chunks function that could do for you is the following:

```
def chunks_series(s):
    subsets = []
    for i in range(s.max() + 1):
        subset = s[s == i]
        subsets.append(subset.values)
    return subsets

subsets = chunks_series(df['col1'])
```

Or you can do everything in the same loop:

```
n_core = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_core)   
s = df['col1']
subset_results = []

for i in range(s.max() + 1):
    subset = s[s == i]
    subset_results.append(p.map(f, subset))
```

I had preferred to introduce a chunk function, even if for your case it does not introduce advantages, to make the code more clear and generalizable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to subset on the basis of col1. chunks will give equal subset of the data which is not I'm looking forward to.